# Is it possible to create a multilevel navigation with AMP sidebar?

Tags: list, navigation, sidebar, amp-html

I want to recreate our mobile page navigation for our AMP site. The problem is that it has multiple levels - so there are lists in the list. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<link to a section>">section</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="<link to another section>">section</a>
        <span>some button that open a sub navigation via javascript</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<link to a subsection>">subsection</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

However even it's quite simple in AMP this seems to be tricky. I couldn't find any example. According to https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-sidebar an `amp-sidebar` within an `amp-sidebar` is not possible since `amp-sidebar` has to be a child of `body`. Using a list in a list can't be used like on the mobile page that easily because: Javascript magic to toggle the subnav is restricted. `:hover` also won't work to show the subnav since it's for mobile devices.

Is there a valid solution to this problem and if yes how is it done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes It is possible to create a multilevel navigation with AMP sidebar.

[Here is example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqQjvY)

Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="canonical" href="hello-world.html">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
   <style amp-custom>
amp-sidebar {background: #f0f0f0;width: 215px;}
amp-sidebar .submenu {background: #f0f0f0;bottom: 0;/*box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);*/left: 0;position: fixed;right: 0;top: 0;-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);transform: translateX(-100%);-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 233ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.21, 1);transition: -webkit-transform 233ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.21, 1);
transition: transform 233ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.21, 1); transition: transform 233ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.21, 1), -webkit-transform 233ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.21, 1)}
amp-sidebar input:checked+.submenu {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);transform: translateX(0);overflow-y:auto;}
amp-sidebar input[type="checkbox"] {position: absolute;visibility: hidden}
amp-sidebar .menu-item {color: #000;display: block;position: relative;text-transform: none}

amp-sidebar .menu-layer .items {left: 0;position: absolute;right: 0;}/*** overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll; 27 june ***/
amp-sidebar .menu-layer .submenu .items {overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll;}
amp-sidebar .menu-layer.primary {height: 100%;position: relative}
amp-sidebar .menu-layer.primary .items { bottom: 0px;top:50px;padding: 0 10px;}
amp-sidebar .menu-layer.secondary { z-index: 2}
amp-sidebar .menu-layer.tertiary { z-index: 3}
amp-sidebar .menu-layer.secondary .items, amp-sidebar .menu-layer.tertiary .items {bottom:0;top:60px;}
amp-sidebar .has-sub-level::after {width: 15px;height: 15px;content: '';position: absolute;right: 15px; top: calc(50% - 8px); background:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/271/271228.svg) no-repeat;}
amp-sidebar .close-button { border: 0; position: absolute;left: 10px;top: 10px; width: 35px;height: 35px;background:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32178.svg) no-repeat; background-size:25px; font-size: 0px;font-family:arial, sans-serif;}
amp-sidebar .return-button {color: #b3b3b3;left: 15px;position: absolute;top: 22px;font-size: 0px;}
amp-sidebar .return-button::before {border: 0;content: '';margin-right: 5px;position: relative;top: 0px;background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/109/109618.svg) no-repeat; width: 30px;height: 30px;display: block;}
amp-sidebar .submenu .return-button + #menu-button {display: none;}
amp-sidebar .menu-layer.secondary .items .level1 li {border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;padding: 8px 5px;}

.hamburger{-webkit-appearance:none;background:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/128/128453.svg) no-repeat;border:0px;font-size:0px;width:48px;height:48px;padding:0;margin:5px; outline:none;z-index:99;background-position:center center;}
.sideNavi > a, .sideNavi > label, .items > a, .items > label {font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;padding: 8px 10px;font-family:arial, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;}
span.whats-new{color:#dc4a36;}
.secondary.submenu >.items>label{font-size:12px;text-transform: uppercase}
.submenu a{font-size: 12px;font-family:arial, sans-serif;padding: 5px 10px;}
span.top-sale-style{background:#3e3e3e;margin-left: 4px;font-size:10px;padding: 0px 3px;text-transform: capitalize;color:#fff;font-weight: bold;border-radius: 2px;display:inline-block;height:15px; line-height:15px;}
.top-new-style {background:#fff;border: 1px solid #e55049;border-radius: 2px;color: #e55049;
display: inline-block;font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;margin-left: 4px;padding: 0px 3px;text-transform: capitalize;height:15px;line-height:15px;}
.sale-style {background:#3e3e3e;border-radius: 2px; color: #fff;display: inline-block;height: 15px;line-height: 15px;font-size: 10px; margin-left: 4px;padding: 0px 3px;text-transform: capitalize; vertical-align: middle;}
</style>
   <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
   <script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
   <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <amp-sidebar id='sidebar' side='left' layout='nodisplay'>
  <form class="menu-layer primary" action="/" target="_top">
    <button type="reset" class="close-button" id="menu-button" on='tap:sidebar.toggle'>X</button>
    <div class="items sideNavi">
        <label class="menu-item item-layer-1 has-sub-level active"><input type="checkbox">
        Lavel 1 (with sub menu)
          <div class="submenu menu-layer secondary">
            <div class="return-button">Back</div>
            <button type="reset" class="close-button" id="menu-button" on='tap:sidebar.toggle'>X</button>
            <div class="items">
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 2</a>
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </label>

         <label class="menu-item item-layer-1 has-sub-level active"><input type="checkbox">
        Lavel 1
          <div class="submenu menu-layer secondary">
            <div class="return-button">Back</div>
            <button type="reset" class="close-button" id="menu-button" on='tap:sidebar.toggle'>X</button>
            <div class="items">



        <label class="menu-item item-layer-1 has-sub-level"><input type="checkbox">
            Lavel 2
          <div class="submenu menu-layer secondary">
            <div class="return-button">Back</div>
            <button type="reset" class="close-button" id="menu-button" on='tap:sidebar.toggle'>X</button>
            <div class="items">
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 3</a>
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 3</a>  
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </label>

         <label class="menu-item item-layer-1 has-sub-level"><input type="checkbox">
            Lavel 2
          <div class="submenu menu-layer secondary">
            <div class="return-button">Back</div>
            <button type="reset" class="close-button" id="menu-button" on='tap:sidebar.toggle'>X</button>
            <div class="items">
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 3</a>
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 3</a>  
                <a class="menu-item item-layer-2" href="#">Lavel 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </label>


            </div>
          </div>
        </label>

        <a class="menu-item item-layer-3" href="#"> Lavel 1 (without sub menu) </a>



    </div>
</form>
</amp-sidebar>

 <button class="tab hamburger" id="menu-button" on='tap:sidebar.toggle'>=</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks promissing. It even has some fancy animations. With using a form it looks a bit hacky and I thought the transition property is restricted in AMP but it indeed validates :)

Answer (score 6):

This is an alternate to the checkbox hack. Using amp-bind to switch classes and some accessibility consideration: https://codepen.io/RickRX/pen/BEzyJm (still WIP)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡ lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AMP Mobile Nav</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="index.php">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
      -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }
  </style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

  <style amp-custom>
    body {
      width: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: lightgrey;
      font-family: "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.6;
    }

    .headerbar {
      background: #ffffff;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .hamburger,
    .site-name {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    amp-sidebar,
    amp-sidebar .submenu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    amp-sidebar .main-menu,
    amp-sidebar .submenu {
      overflow: auto;
    }

    amp-sidebar .submenu {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: fixed;
    }

    amp-sidebar .hide-submenu {
      visibility: hidden;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    amp-sidebar .show-submenu {
      visibility: visible;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }

    amp-sidebar .hide-parent {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    amp-sidebar .truncate {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    amp-sidebar .link-container {
      display: block;
      height: 44px;
      line-height: 44px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
      padding: 0 1rem;
    }

    amp-sidebar a {
      min-width: 44px;
      min-height: 44px;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }


    amp-sidebar .submenu-icon {
      padding-right: 44px;
    }

    amp-sidebar .submenu-icon::after {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      height: 44px;
      width: 44px;
      content: '';
      background-size: 1rem;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
    }

    amp-sidebar .controls {
      display: flex;
      height: 50px;
      background: #f0f0f0;
    }

    amp-sidebar .controls a {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    amp-sidebar .controls span {
      line-height: 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    amp-sidebar nav>.controls>a:first-of-type {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    amp-sidebar .controls a svg {
      height: 1rem;
      width: 1rem;
    }

    amp-sidebar .link-icon {
      float: left;
      height: 44px;
      margin-right: 0.75rem;
    }

    amp-sidebar .link-icon>svg {
      height: 44px;
    }

    amp-sidebar {
      background: #fff;
      color: #232323;
      fill: #232323;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.18rem;
      font-size: 0.875rem;
    }

    amp-sidebar a {
      color: #232323;
      text-transform: none;
      letter-spacing: normal;
    }

    div[class*="-sidebar-mask"] {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }



    amp-sidebar a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
      fill: #232323;
    }

    amp-sidebar .view-all {
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<amp-sidebar id='header-sidebar' side='left' layout='nodisplay'>
        <nav>

            <div
                class="controls"
                [class]="hidePrimary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                aria-label="Menu controls">
                <a
                    tabindex="0"
                    role="button"
                    aria-label="">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                </a>
                <span class="truncate">Menu</span>
                <a
                    tabindex="0"
                    role="button"
                    on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                    aria-label="Close Menu">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="main-menu items"
                role="menu"
                aria-label="Menu links"
                [class]="hidePrimary ? 'main-menu items hide-parent' : 'main-menu items'">


                                            <a
                            class="link-container submenu-icon truncate"
                            role="menuitem"
                            tabindex="0"
                            aria-label="Mens"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_0: !level_1_0, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                            title="Mens">
                                                        Mens                        </a>

                        <div class="submenu hide-submenu"
                            [class]="(level_1_0 ? 'submenu show-submenu' : 'submenu hide-submenu') + ' ' + (hideSecondary ? 'hide-parent' : '')"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-label="Mens">
                            <div
                                class="controls"
                                [class]="hideSecondary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                                aria-label="Mens controls">
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_0: !level_1_0, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                                    aria-label="Return to Menu">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                                </a>
                                <span class="truncate">Mens</span>
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                                    aria-label="Close Mens">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                                </a>
                            </div>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Clothing" >
                                                                                Clothing                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Footwear" >
                                                                                Footwear                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Accessories" >
                                                                                Accessories                                    </a>


                                                            <a class="link-container view-all truncate" href="/link" title="Mens" >
                                    View All Mens                                </a>

                        </div>


                                            <a
                            class="link-container submenu-icon truncate"
                            role="menuitem"
                            tabindex="0"
                            aria-label="Womens"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_1: !level_1_1, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                            title="Womens">
                                                        Womens                        </a>

                        <div class="submenu hide-submenu"
                            [class]="(level_1_1 ? 'submenu show-submenu' : 'submenu hide-submenu') + ' ' + (hideSecondary ? 'hide-parent' : '')"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-label="Womens">
                            <div
                                class="controls"
                                [class]="hideSecondary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                                aria-label="Womens controls">
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_1: !level_1_1, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                                    aria-label="Return to Menu">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                                </a>
                                <span class="truncate">Womens</span>
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                                    aria-label="Close Womens">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                                </a>
                            </div>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Clothing" >
                                                                                Clothing                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Footwear" >
                                                                                Footwear                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Accessories" >
                                                                                Accessories                                    </a>


                                                            <a class="link-container view-all truncate" href="/link" title="Womens" >
                                    View All Womens                                </a>

                        </div>


                                            <a
                            class="link-container submenu-icon truncate"
                            role="menuitem"
                            tabindex="0"
                            aria-label="Kids"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_2: !level_1_2, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                            title="Kids">
                                                        Kids                        </a>

                        <div class="submenu hide-submenu"
                            [class]="(level_1_2 ? 'submenu show-submenu' : 'submenu hide-submenu') + ' ' + (hideSecondary ? 'hide-parent' : '')"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-label="Kids">
                            <div
                                class="controls"
                                [class]="hideSecondary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                                aria-label="Kids controls">
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_2: !level_1_2, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                                    aria-label="Return to Menu">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                                </a>
                                <span class="truncate">Kids</span>
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                                    aria-label="Close Kids">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                                </a>
                            </div>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Clothing" >
                                                                                Clothing                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Footwear" >
                                                                                Footwear                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Accessories" >
                                                                                Accessories                                    </a>


                                                            <a class="link-container view-all truncate" href="/link" title="Kids" >
                                    View All Kids                                </a>

                        </div>


                                            <a
                            class="link-container submenu-icon truncate"
                            role="menuitem"
                            tabindex="0"
                            aria-label="Brands"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_3: !level_1_3, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                            title="Brands">
                                                        Brands                        </a>

                        <div class="submenu hide-submenu"
                            [class]="(level_1_3 ? 'submenu show-submenu' : 'submenu hide-submenu') + ' ' + (hideSecondary ? 'hide-parent' : '')"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-label="Brands">
                            <div
                                class="controls"
                                [class]="hideSecondary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                                aria-label="Brands controls">
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on="tap:AMP.setState({level_1_3: !level_1_3, hidePrimary: !hidePrimary})"
                                    aria-label="Return to Menu">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                                </a>
                                <span class="truncate">Brands</span>
                                <a
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    role="button"
                                    on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                                    aria-label="Close Brands">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                                </a>
                            </div>



                                                                    <a
                                        class="link-container submenu-icon truncate"
                                        role="menuitem"
                                        tabindex="0"
                                        aria-label="A-B"
                                        aria-haspopup="true"
                                        on="tap:AMP.setState({level_2_0: !level_2_0, hideSecondary: !hideSecondary})"
                                        title="A-B">
                                                                                A-B                                    </a>

                                    <div class="submenu hide-submenu"
                                        [class]="(level_2_0 ? 'submenu show-submenu' : 'submenu hide-submenu') + ' ' + (hideTertiary ? 'hide-parent' : '')"
                                        role="menu"
                                        aria-label="A-B">
                                        <div
                                            class="controls"
                                            [class]="hideTertiary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                                            aria-label="A-B controls">
                                            <a
                                                tabindex="0"
                                                role="button"
                                                on="tap:AMP.setState({level_2_0: !level_2_0, hideSecondary: !hideSecondary})"
                                                aria-label="Return to Brands">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                                            </a>
                                            <span class="truncate">A-B</span>
                                            <a
                                                tabindex="0"
                                                role="button"
                                                on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                                                aria-label="Close A-B">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                                            </a>
                                        </div>



                                                                                            <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Armani" >
                                                                                                        Armani                                                </a>



                                                                                            <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="BOSS" >
                                                                                                        BOSS                                                </a>



                                    </div>


                                                                    <a
                                        class="link-container submenu-icon truncate"
                                        role="menuitem"
                                        tabindex="0"
                                        aria-label="C-F"
                                        aria-haspopup="true"
                                        on="tap:AMP.setState({level_2_1: !level_2_1, hideSecondary: !hideSecondary})"
                                        title="C-F">
                                                                                C-F                                    </a>

                                    <div class="submenu hide-submenu"
                                        [class]="(level_2_1 ? 'submenu show-submenu' : 'submenu hide-submenu') + ' ' + (hideTertiary ? 'hide-parent' : '')"
                                        role="menu"
                                        aria-label="C-F">
                                        <div
                                            class="controls"
                                            [class]="hideTertiary ? 'controls hide-parent' : 'controls'"
                                            aria-label="C-F controls">
                                            <a
                                                tabindex="0"
                                                role="button"
                                                on="tap:AMP.setState({level_2_1: !level_2_1, hideSecondary: !hideSecondary})"
                                                aria-label="Return to Brands">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>                                            </a>
                                            <span class="truncate">C-F</span>
                                            <a
                                                tabindex="0"
                                                role="button"
                                                on='tap:header-sidebar.toggle'
                                                aria-label="Close C-F">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z"/></svg>                                            </a>
                                        </div>



                                                                                            <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="Channel" >
                                                                                                        Channel                                                </a>



                                                                                            <a class="link-container truncate" tabindex="0" href="/link" title="CK Jeans" >
                                                                                                        CK Jeans                                                </a>



                                    </div>


                        </div>
                                                </div>
        </nav>
    </amp-sidebar>

  <header class="headerbar">
    <div class="hamburger" role="button" aria-label="mobile menu" on="tap:header-sidebar.toggle" tabindex="0">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 6h-24v-4h24v4zm0 4h-24v4h24v-4zm0 8h-24v4h24v-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="site-name">AMP Mobile Nav</div>
  </header>

  <div class="info">
    <p>some content...</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the amp-nested-menu component. You just have to expand the amp-sidebar if you are using it. Here an example:

```
<amp-sidebar id="sidebar" layout="nodisplay" side="left">
<amp-nested-menu layout="fill">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div amp-nested-submenu-open class="nested-arrow">Test</div>
            <div amp-nested-submenu>
                <ul>
                    <li><div amp-nested-submenu-close>go back</div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
                    ....
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</amp-nested-menu></amp-sidebar>
```

Comment: Please don't just put a plain URL in you answer. It's better to include some example and explanation.

Comment: @mate00 I removed the link and posted an example, thanks for the hint!